# Best mobile store locator solution with 10.000+ markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm developing a store locator web-application for mobile (iPhone). The idea is standard, the device uses its geolocation feature to determince the location and should then display the 5-10 closest stores on a map. My problem is essentially that I have too many stores (10.000+) and haven't yet been able to create a nice user eperience.

I realize this may be a bit much to ask but I'd love to hear your thoughts on this..

**PROBLEM SCOPE:**

i) I figure I can only load some of the markers at once rather than all of them which I found that a lot of the <100 stores-finder apps do.

ii) It should be bad connection friendly: i.e. google maps should for example not be made to zoom in and out unecessearily causing new tiles to load (and a empty screen to show if the connection is bad)

iii) it has to somehow cope with the fact that the device gps/tower triangulation can be slow to get an sufficiently accurate fix on your position (often a minute or two if indoors or in an rural area)

**SOLUTIONS I've tried:**

I) Use getCurrentPositition and from that lat/lng load 5 closest markers. Issue: the snapshot positioning is inaccurate and often the 'wrong' 5 stores are loaded.

II) Use watchPosition until accuracy reaches <100m and then load closest 5 markers. Issue: often takes way to long to get the position (often >1 minute), not a good UX.

III) Same as II only markers are loaded contionously while it finding exact position. Issues: It gets real 'jumpy' using fitbounds() or panTo() every time there is an update. I.e. if the user tries to say click a marker while the map is still in 'find position'-mode they will be intrerupted by the map changing bounds and loading more markers.

IV) Fit bounds to an approximate position using watchPosition and a fixed zoom and use center of the map to get the closest stores. Continously load markers as watchPosition finds a better approximate center or the user himself pans the map. Issues: Again, a bit jumpy since watchPosition updates alot. No 'your position' marker.

**BACKGROUND INFO:**

I'm using much of the standard google method of creating a store finder, shown here: http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

Google Maps v3 API, MySQL database, Haversine formula, JSONP asychronous loading of marker-data, no libraries (jQuery or such). Loading 5-10 new markers with this method usually takes less than 1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I don't know what watchCurrentPosition is, I'm going to assume you meant to say watchPosition; which is defined in the HTML5 Geolocation spec.*

- I wouldn't use `watchPosition` for this.  It's technically [defined](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#watch-position) to track changes in position, which don't necessarily translate to increases in accuracy.  While I'm not an expert on mobile device power consumption, I'd bet that it uses a lot more power to fire up the GPS and keep it on than to get 1 really good position fix, which is what `getCurrentPosition` is designed for.
- I'd be surprised if this was actually a GPS / sensor fix-time problem.  Lots of websites used `getCurrentPosition` to find the user's current position and most mobile devices can do it within a few seconds, not much different from an AJAX call.  I'd play with the `PositionOptions` [settings](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_options_interface) to set a reasonable timeout, maxAge, and play with the enableHighAccuracy value.
- If your 10K stores are within a 2-5 mile radius then you definitely have a hard problem on your hands :-D, but otherwise the data you're getting back from the Geolocation API should be able to narrow it down a handful of stores within a reasonable accuracy.  The Geolocation API might not return a lat/lng representing your exact street address, but it should get you a location within the correct city, if not cluster of streets.
- I'd decompose this into two problems: 1 - Getting an acceptably accurate position (lat, lng) via the Geolocation API.  2 - Finding stores near position (lat, lng).  It'll be much easier to ask focused questions if you're having troubles with part 1 or part 2

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant watchPosition (edited). Some good points there, thanks. In my experience, and I've tested this alot, getCurrentPosition is only good for an approximate position, and what I'd really like is to get same accuracy found in the Google Maps App (iphone).